# Separating rows by form_id

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to sqlalchemy and flask for that matter but I'm using them for a personal project and i need some help.

I have a column called form_id:

```
class Entries(db.Model):
    form_id = db.Column(db.String(12), index=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=True, unique=False)
```

and I'm generating that form id randomly every time the page is refreshed:

`form_id = generate_formid(12)`

which gives me a 12 character long alphanumeric string.

What i want to do is grab all entries for current_user but separate them by form_id into lists without knowing what the form_id is.

So for example (not real code):

```
for form_id in query:
    get all rows and add them to a list
```

from:
`Entries.query.filter_by(owner_id=current_user.username)`

So i need to filter_by owner_id and somehow pull out data for every different form_id into its own list.

What would be the best way of doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function to do this.

```py
import itertools

# Order the query by form_id, because groupby expects a sorted iterable. 
ents = Entries.query.filter_by(owner_id=current_user.username).order_by(Entries.form_id)

# Tell groupby that we want to group by form_id, using the key parameter
gb = itertools.groupby(ents, key=lambda ent: ent.form_id)

# Create the list of lists
grouped = [list(group) for _, group in gb]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Marked as answer but cant upvote it because i lack enough reputation (my first post). In any case awesome solution works like a charm!

Comment: So excellent code, I upvoted it instead of you @cstX